# The 1th argument dim does not have a specified value or default value

Tags: java, android, pytorch, jit

I'm trying to deploy an image to image model on Android. Model consists of encoder and decoder.
The encoder works fine. But this issue comes in decoder. My model takes one tensor as input and it should return a tensor of size [1,3,1024,1024] as output. But there comes a Fatal in the app.

```
final long[] styleshape = new long[]{3};
final FloatBuffer styledBuffer = Tensor.allocateFloatBuffer(3);
styledBuffer.put(-0.4951f);
styledBuffer.put(-1.0065f);
styledBuffer.put(-1.0413f);

styledBuffer.get(0);
Tensor styledTensor = Tensor.fromBlob(styledBuffer, styleshape);
IValue style = IValue.from(styledTensor);
final Tensor styledOutputTensor = decoderModule.forward(style).toTensor();
```

```
                                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=101, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/... flg=0x1 }} to activity {org.pytorch.helloworld/org.pytorch.helloworld.MainActivity}: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Error happened at preparing for default values for the argument. The 1th argument dim does not have a specified value or default value.
```

I tried passing a random tensor of the similar shape and then I didn't get the error.

```
def forward(self,  style_tensor):
        spade_input=None 
        pure_generation=False
        content_list=[]
        content_list.append(torch.rand([1, 192, 256, 256]))
        content_list.append(torch.rand([1, 5, 512, 512]))
        content_list.append(torch.rand([1, 5, 1024, 1024]))
        style_tensor = torch.randn(1,1,3,1)
        style_tensor=style_tensor.view(1,1,3,1)
        if self.pred_adain_params:
            adain_params = self.adain_net(style_tensor)
            self.assign_adain_params(adain_params, self)

        if self.pred_conv_kernel:
            assert style_tensor.size(0) == 1, 'prediction of convilution does not work with batch size > 1'
            self.assign_style(style_tensor.view(1, -1), self)

        tensor = module_list_forward(self.body, content_list[0], spade_input)
        for skip_content, up_layer, up_postprocess_layer, skip_preprocess_layer in     zip(content_list[1:], self.upsample_head, self.upsample_postprocess,self.skip_preprocess):                            
                                                                                       
                                                                                       
                                                                                       
            tensor = up_layer(tensor)
            skip_tensor = skip_preprocess_layer(skip_content)
            tensor = torch.cat([tensor, skip_tensor], 1)
            tensor = up_postprocess_layer(tensor)
        for layer in self.model_postprocess:
            tensor = layer(tensor)    

        tensor = torch.tanh(tensor[:, : 3])

                            
        #ret = torch.randn([1, 3, 1024, 1024])
        
        return tensor
```

Expecting a Tensor but getting the above error.

Comment: Turns out there was an issue with my model. There were many forward calls in the other classes the my main model was inheriting from. I removed those forward calls and fixed the issue